# App crashing when trying to use performSegue(withIdentifier: , sender: )

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently trying to perform a segue to a new ViewController right away if my app is opened via a notification sent from Firebase.

I'm trying to perform the segue with the code `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: nil)`, where "testSegue" is the identifier of a segue in my Storyboard going from the ViewController to the SecondViewController (different class).

The issue is that this line is crashing my app, and I can't easily debug this due to the fact that I'm launching the app from the notification, and not from Xcode.

I also delayed the code by adding in a Timer that runs this line 5 seconds later, to determine that it is at this line when the crash occurs, and have also tried using `present(viewControllerToPresent: ...)`.

If anyone could point out why the crash is occurring, or how to debug the error in this situation, or any alternative ways to have it go the ViewController I need automatically, that would be great, thanks.

Some additional code from AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print(userInfo)

    let url = userInfo["url"]

    print("url is: \(String(describing: url))")

    if url != nil {

        vc.defaults.set("\(String(describing: url))", forKey: "urlDef")

        vc.defaults.set(true, forKey: "hasRun")

        initialVC.testingFunc()

        print("Func done")

    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    print("Func finished")
}
```

Some additional code from ViewController.swift

```
var funcTimer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func testingFunc() {

    funcTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.triggerSegue), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    print("The timer has begun")

}

func triggerSegue() {

    print("Trigger segue func has begun")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: nil)

}
```

[image: My segue in the Storyboard]

Comment: what is your crash log

Comment: I don't have one, due to the fact that I'm not running the app from Xcode, as I'm launching it from the notification

Comment: it's a wild guess without the crash log, but first thing I would do is check whether you are on the main thread.. try to put that presentation code on the main thread..

Comment: where are initilize this initialVC?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ You were right, hadn't thought about that somehow, but putting it on the main thread works, so I think I can work it out from here now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to Main thread when you are presenting the viewController.

```
func triggerSegue() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```